# How to have multiple rewrite endpoints in the same URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I'd like to add multiple query_var / value pairs to any URL.
For example the base URL of a page is:

```
example.com/nice-page/
```

I can already achieve one endpoint like (for example, an on-page subgallery):

```
example.com/nice-page/my-gallery/animals/cats
```

Where `my-gallery` is the query_var and `animals/cats` is its value. Using this:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('my-gallery', EP_PAGES);
add_rewrite_endpoint('my-lightbox', EP_PAGES);
```

I also need this to work:

```
example.com/nice-page/my-gallery/animals/cats/my-lightbox/1234
```

Where I'd like to register `my-lightbox` as an additional endpoint or query_var, because it could be used independently from without `my-gallery`, such as:

```
example.com/another-page/my-lightbox/2345
```

Currently I get the entire `animals/cats/my-lightbox/1234` as the value. **I can't make WP aware that a new query_var starts at `my-lightbox` when `my-gallery` is alrady present.** It seems that rewrite tags are acting on the entirety of the input URL, and endpoints are acting on the end of the input URL, but the regex $ end-anchor is always there. Is it even possible to use the rewrite api to prettify multiple query_vars into a complex URL?

Comment: for more complex patterns with multiple query vars, you'll need to use `add_rewrite_rule`

Comment: I see, but don't I need to build the entire query starting from index.php in the 2nd parameter? I'd like to augment what's already there by other rules (I don't know whether this will be added to a page or whatever).

Comment: It's going to involve some level of repetition, there's no automatic way to do it. Maybe `add_permastruct` would help simplify things. You can use rewrite tags to define structures and it will generate the rules for you from that.

Answer (score 4):

> I also need this to work:
>
> ```
> example.com/nice-page/my-gallery/animals/cats/my-lightbox/1234
> ```
>
> Where I'd like to register `my-lightbox` as an additional endpoint or
>   query_var, because it could be used independently from without
>   `my-gallery`, such as:
>
> ```
> example.com/another-page/my-lightbox/2345
> ```

Here's an example of doing it using `add_rewrite_rule()`:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    // This will let you use get_query_var( 'my-gallery' ).
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-gallery', EP_PAGES );

    // This will let you use get_query_var( 'my-lightbox' ).
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-lightbox', EP_PAGES );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '(.?.+?)/(?:my-gallery/(.+?)/my-lightbox/(\d+)|my-gallery/(.+?)|/?my-lightbox/(\d+))/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&my-gallery=$matches[2]&my-lightbox=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );

    // This is just for testing purposes. You should instead go to the Permalink
    // Settings page and click on the Save Changes button to flush the rules. =)
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
} );
```

[EDIT] Alternate version without using `add_rewrite_endpoint()`:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $qv ) {
    // This will let you use get_query_var( 'my-gallery' ).
    $qv[] = 'my-gallery';

    // This will let you use get_query_var( 'my-lightbox' ).
    $qv[] = 'my-lightbox';

    return $qv;
} );

add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '(.?.+?)/(?:my-gallery/(.+?)/my-lightbox/(\d+)|my-gallery/(.+?)|/?my-lightbox/(\d+))/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&my-gallery=$matches[2]&my-lightbox=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
} );
```

And I have tested it on these URLs:

- example.com/nice-page/my-gallery/animals/cats/my-lightbox/1234
- example.com/nice-page/my-gallery/animals/cats
- example.com/nice-page/my-lightbox/1234

..where `get_query_var( 'my-gallery' )` returns `animals/cats` (for the first and second URLs) and `get_query_var( 'my-lightbox' )` returns `1234` (for the first and third URLs).